# Notification getIntent().getExtras() gets the same bundle

Tags: android

The problem im having is I call sendAffimationNotice() twice passing a unique `aff_id` each time (as confirmed by printing "putting " + `aff_id`).

This prints `'putting 1'` and on the second call `'putting 2'`.

The phone now has 2 notifications. Though when both are clicked they both have the same ID toasted in the onCreate method on the intents activity.

Both times it prints "ID is: 1" even though both notifications are unique.

```
public class PossAffNotification{

private static int notif_ID = 1;
private static NotificationManager notificationManager;
private static Notification note;
private static PendingIntent contentIntent;

public static void sendAffimationNotice(Context ctx, String title,String contentText,int aff_id){

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    note = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, contentText, System.currentTimeMillis() );

    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, com.mindfsck.PossAff.MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("aff_id",aff_id);
    System.out.println("putting " + aff_id);

    notificationIntent.setAction("com.mindfsck.PossAff.intent.action.aff");

    notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    note.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, contentText, contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);

    notif_ID += 1;
}

   };

    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,PAService.class);
            this.startService(serviceIntent);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras !=null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID is: " + extras.getInt("aff_id"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Intent` is the same on all non-extra parameters (e.g., action). Hence, you get the same `PendingIntent` back from your `getActivity()` call, as there is only one `PendingIntent` per distinct `Intent`. You need to change something -- beyond extras -- in your second `Intent`, such as a different action string.

Comment: Thanks, this explains in more detail the problem described by CommonsWare http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be237f20b9e97ef0/4dc3d3593a13bdb8?show_docid=4dc3d3593a13bdb8&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

The problem for this issue came from this line:

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

The last parameter shouldn't be 0 it should be PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

otherwise in notificationIntent you will receive same data all the time

Answer (score -1):

This article of mine may be helpful here: "[A pitfal in PendingIntent](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.de/2010/12/pitfall-in-pendingintent-with-solution.html)"

The issue basically comes from the fact, that the system does not assume that only because we pass a new Intent object to the pending intent, we want this new intent object to be delivered and just keeps the old (initial) pending intent alive.

To get the desired semantics, we need to pass a flag to tell the system:

```
PendingIntent pintent = 
   PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: **Link has rotted.** This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).